How can "Lo Sasur" be used as a primary source for the power of rabbinic legislation?
The context of "Lo Sasur" is that when the law isn't clear the kohanim (and the shofet) at the mikdash are the final authority. See Devarim 17:8-11

(ח) כִּי יִפָּלֵא מִמְּךָ דָבָר לַמִּשְׁפָּט בֵּין דָּם לְדָם בֵּין דִּין לְדִין וּבֵין נֶגַע לָנֶגַע דִּבְרֵי רִיבֹת בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ וְקַמְתָּ וְעָלִיתָ אֶל הַמָּקוֹם אֲשֶׁר יִבְחַר י"י אֱלֹהֶיךָ בּוֹ. (ט) וּבָאתָ אֶל הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וְאֶל הַשֹּׁפֵט אֲשֶׁר יִהְיֶה בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם וְדָרַשְׁתָּ וְהִגִּידוּ לְךָ אֵת דְּבַר הַמִּשְׁפָּט. (י) וְעָשִׂיתָ עַל פִּי הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר יַגִּידוּ לְךָ מִן הַמָּקוֹם הַהוּא אֲשֶׁר יִבְחַר י"י וְשָׁמַרְתָּ לַעֲשׂוֹת כְּכֹל אֲשֶׁר יוֹרוּךָ. (יא) עַל פִּי הַתּוֹרָה אֲשֶׁר יוֹרוּךָ וְעַל הַמִּשְׁפָּט אֲשֶׁר יֹאמְרוּ לְךָ תַּעֲשֶׂה לֹא תָסוּר מִן הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר יַגִּידוּ לְךָ יָמִין וּשְׂמֹאל.
(8) If there arises a matter too hard for you in judgment, between blood and blood, between plea and plea, and between stroke and stroke, being matters of controversy within your gates; then you shall arise, and go up to the place which Hashem your God shall choose. (9) And you shall come to the priests, the Levites, and to the judge who shall be in those days: and you shall inquire; and they shall tell you the matter of judgment. (10) You shall do according to the matter which they shall tell you from that place which Hashem shall choose; and you shall observe to do according to all that they shall teach you. (11) According to the teaching which they shall teach you, and according to the judgment which they shall tell you, you shall do; you shall not turn aside from the matter which they shall show you, to the right hand, nor to the left.

Chazal famously use this as the primary source for the rabbinic power to enact new legislation (ie takanos, gezeiros, etc)
As peshuto shel mikra refers to the adjudication of difficult cases, (see eg R A ibn Ezra על פי התורה אשר יורוך – בדבר המופלא.
ACCORDING TO THE LAW WHICH THEY SHALL TEACH THEE. With regard to the matter that is too hard for you) how can Chazal use this as the source for their legislative ability when the plain meaning and context refers to judicial authority only?
(Qualification: this seems to be an issue for Rambam only, who understands [ShM Shoresh 1]—as b Shab 23 seems to indicate—that Lo Sasur also includes freestanding rabbinic legislation. Ramban vehemently disagrees. He is of the opinion that only rabbinic explanations of the Torah [via interpreting a word's meaning and wielding the middos shehatorah nidreshes bahem] are covered by Lo Sasur, takanos and gezeiros are most assuredly not.)

I think you're having difficulty because your premise is incorrect.
The basis for enacting new legislation actually comes from an injunction to do so found in Vayikra 18:30:

ושמרתם את משמרתי לבלתי עשות מחקות התועבות אשר נעשו לפניכם ולא תטמאו בהם אני ה' א-להיכם
And you shall observe My charge, not to commit any of the abominable practices that were done before you, and you shall not become defiled by them. I am the Lord your God.

Rashi there says:

להזהיר בית דין על כך
To exhort the courts about this.

The Gra says:

לעשות משמרת למשמרת
To make a guarding for the guarding.

In other words, to enact further decrees to set up "guardrails" against the commandments.
Seforno, in greater detail, says:

שמרו גם את המצות שצויתי לשמירה וגדר שלא תכשלו בכל אלה, כמו אסורי מאכלות וטומאת נדה וזבה ויולדת וזולתם, ובזה האופן לא תטמאו בהם:
Also guard the commandments which I commanded as a protection and "guardrail," so that you won't stumble in these. For example, forbidden foods, ritual impurities of niddah/zavah/postpartum and others. In this way you won't become impure through them.

In other words, the Torah itself instructs Chazal to make guardrails. The setting up of additional injunctions by Chazal is a direct and explicit commandment, outside of the judicial authority granted to them by the Torah.

Same question applies there as well (which is from b. yev 21), see Onkelos and ibn Ezra that translate as "Keep my above mentioned laws". "Lo sasur" is used in the B Talmud (eg shab 23) and Rambam (eg Mamrim 1:1) as the primary biblical source for rabbinic legislative authority.
